# Wordpress CSS Lost After Migration

Tags: php, mysql, css, wordpress

I am really new to Wordpress and I haven't use it before. So I have source code of Wordpress which is already installed somewhere on says `www.theshop.com`. I took out the source code and upload it into another server `xx.xx.xx.xx/theshop`. I have also set up the MySQL and the it's database is already there.

When I go to `xx.xx.xx.xx/theshop` in the browser, the page is successfully displayed, however the CSS is missing. The menu link also seems to hold the previous domain still like `theshop.com/theshop/?pageid=1`. I have changed the DB config in `wp-config.php` however I could not find how to solve this absolute path or domain issue maybe.

Sorry if I miss anything but please let me know if any other information required. Again this is my first involvement in Wordpress. There is no `cPanel` or any automated installer for Wordpress on my server. Plus the browser says my Wordpress is already installed. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you make sure to move the stylesheet(s) over too?

Comment: @PaulRandall Yes I believe so. I moved whole completed source code in one short.

Comment: The CSS _should_ be stored in its own directory. Have you checked to make sure it's actually there?

Comment: @PaulRandall Yes I can see the CSS directory. The path must be messed up somewhere.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem, I have same issue right now.